# ¿Cómo podría enviar notificación al smartphone si alguien sube archivo en mi web?

Tags: php, android, push-notification

Tengo un formulario que sube una fotografía a mi web, hecho con php (vamos, un típico formulario que sube una fotografía).

```html
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Y en el servidor:

```php
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

El caso es que me gustaría que si alguien envía un archivo, mediante código php se me notificase en mi smartphone Android.

¿Hay alguna forma?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

La forma mas simple es enviarte un correo electrónico....para enviar notificaciones necesitas hacer un app que las pueda manejar....

Comment: Comprendo, creía que era algo más sencillo. ¿Hay alguna forma de que llegue el correo de forma instantanea? o sea, yo por ejemplo no recibo al instante los correos en el Thunderbird si no que tardan unos segundos.

Comment: Al final te he hecho caso, me rindo jeje. Gracias por tu ayuda.